# Confusion with the field of definition of a variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes

Fix a field extension $k\subseteq K$ (assume that the fields have characteristic $0$) and consider the two following definitions:

[image]
[image]

Now let's restrict our attention to a closed subscheme  $X\subseteq\mathbb P^n_K$ (i.e. embedded projective variety), I have basically two questions:

- Definition $3.24$ in other terms means that I can find some homogeneous polynomials with coefficients in $k$, whose common zeros set is isomorphic to $X$. Now I don't understand what is the practical meaning of definition $3.25$. I'd like a description in terms of common zeros of polynomials (remember: only in the case of embedded projective varieties).
- In definition $3.25$ it is very strange the fact that one requires the **equality**
  $$W= V\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k} \operatorname{Spec} K$$
  but what happens if one requires the **equality up to isomorphism**? Namely:
  $$W\cong V\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k} \operatorname{Spec} K$$
  (It seems that in our case the two definitions coincide.)

Comment: To understand what can go wrong, consider the case of a complex non-real line inside the complex plane.

Comment: Two subschemes of a given scheme may, or may not, be equal;  "isomorphic subschemes" does not make much sense.

Comment: @abx Yes you are right, this is the point. Two schemes $Y$ and $Y'$ are equal as subschemes of $X$ if they are isomorphic and this isomorphism commutes with two embeddings in $X$

Comment: @abx: I think it depends on how you define a subscheme. Whenever there is a sheaf $I$ with an injective map $I \to O_X$, I'd like to think of it as an ideal sheaf, regardless of whether it is in fact set-theoretically a subsheaf of $O_X$. If you used the functor of points approach, you might say that a subscheme is a special type of subfunctor, but I'm not sure there is much to gain from that point of view. In the end, isn't it just better to define a subscheme as some $Y$ together with an embedding into $X$?

Answer (score 1):

presumably the reason there is an equality in 3.25 instead of an isomorphism is that you don't want $V_K$ to be abstractly isomorphic to $W$, but you want them to be equivalent subschemes of $X_K$ (ie isomorphic in the category of pairs (scheme, embedding)).

At least that's how I would interpret it, but I might be wrong. Also, take $X = P^N$. Saying that $W \subset X_K$ is defined over $k$ means precisely that you can find equations cutting out $X_K$ with coefficients in at most $k$.